convert tab delimited file as json without changing the input key value integer or float and without quote to the value
I'm converting the two column tab delimited file as JSON format, together with set of keys and argument sample_id = 'WGNP1000001'.
Here's my input and expected output format and the code. Appreciate any help.
Python to convert tab delimited file as json with supplied argument and additional keys
Tab delimited input file: WGNP1000001.list.txt
insert_size 447.3
insert_size_std 98.2
pct_properly_paired 97.9
pct_mapped  99.63
yield_bp_q30    1996315
mean_autosome_coverage  0.000644
pct_autosomes_15x   0.000016
mad_autosome_coverage   4

Expected Output without adding double quotes to the values and not adding float to the integer only values eg. mad_autosome_coverage, yield_bp_q30 and pct_autosomes_15x
{
    "sample": {
        "id": "WGNP1000001"
    },
    "wgs_metrics": {
        "insert_size": 447.3,
        "insert_size_std": 98.2,
        "mad_autosome_coverage": 4,
        "mean_autosome_coverage": 0.000644,
        "pct_autosomes_15x": 0.000016,
        "pct_mapped": 99.63,
        "pct_properly_paired": 97.9,
        "yield_bp_q30": 1996315
    }
}

But the following tried code writes (try1) the values with double quotes or (try2) adding the float to the the values of integer only.
Try1 - write the values with double quotes
def raw_data(input_metrics):
    d = {}
    with open(input_metrics) as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line.strip():
                continue
            row = line.split('\t')
            key = row[0]
            value_str = row[1]
            d[key] = value_str.replace("\n", "")
            #try:
            #    value = float(value_str.strip())
            #except ValueError:
            #    value = value_str.strip()
            #d[key] = value
    return d

Output:

{
    "sample": {
        "id": "NA12878"
    },
    "wgs_metrics": {
        "insert_size": "447.3",
        "insert_size_std": "98.2",
        "mad_autosome_coverage": "4",
        "mean_autosome_coverage": "0.000644",
        "pct_autosomes_15x": "0.000016",
        "pct_mapped": "99.63",
        "pct_properly_paired": "97.9",
        "yield_bp_q30": "1996315"
    }
}

Try2 - adding float to the integer only values (yield_bp_q30, mad_autosome_coverage) and log (pct_autosomes_15x)
    def raw_data(input_metrics):
        d = {}
        with open(input_metrics) as f:
            for line in f:
                if not line.strip():
                    continue
                row = line.split('\t')
                key = row[0]
                value_str = row[1]
                try:
                    value = float(value_str.strip())
                except ValueError:
                    value = value_str.strip()
                d[key] = value
        return d

Output:
{
    "sample": {
        "id": "WGNP1000001"
    },
    "wgs_metrics": {
        "insert_size": 447.3,
        "insert_size_std": 98.2,
        "mad_autosome_coverage": 4.0,
        "mean_autosome_coverage": 0.000644,
        "pct_autosomes_15x": 1.6e-05,
        "pct_mapped": 99.63,
        "pct_properly_paired": 97.9,
        "yield_bp_q30": 1996315.0
    }
}

Updated code:
def raw_data(input_metrics):
    d = {}
    with open(input_metrics) as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line.strip():
                continue
            row = line.split('\t')
            key = row[0]
            value_str = row[1]
            try:
                value = int(value_str)
            except ValueError:
                value = float(value_str.strip())
            d[key] = value
    return d


If you want integer values to remain integers, then there needs to be a path through your code where you apply int() to the value read from the file.  Only if that fails should you try float() (as your Try2 is currently doing).
